# Pandas Python : query and where on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have e DataFrame like this:

```
RTD  I   
BA  32    
CA  25    
BA  22
CA  45    
NA  69   
BA  75   
BA  28   
VE  30   
BA  13   
BA  11
```

First:

```
Test= (df.where(df.query('I>0 & RTD =="BA"')).dropna())
```

After I get the new dataframe, without Nan values, like this:

```
RTD  I
BA  32
BA  22
BA  75   
BA  28
BA  13
BA  11
```

Well. The number 32 is present in first position. If i ask: how long has the number 32 is missing from the dataframe, after the first occurence?. The answer should be: 5 times. How you could do using pandas?

I have tried to do:

```
len(df.loc[Test.last_valid_index():]) - 1
```

but it does not work

In essence: how you can perform an additional command on a data frame on which a query is executed, without saving ( ex. to "csv") the new dataframe and act on it?

Comment: Please format Python code as Python code.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [76]: x
Out[76]:
  RTD   I
0  BA  32
2  BA  22
5  BA  75
6  BA  28
8  BA  32   # <-- NOTE: i have intentionally set it to `32`
9  BA  11

In [77]: len(x) - np.argwhere(x.I==32).max() - 1
Out[77]: 1

In [78]: len(x) - np.argwhere(x.I==32).min() - 1
Out[78]: 5
```

Comment: In your example, len(x) - np.argwhere(x.I==32).min() - 1 It should be equal to 3